# python xlrd : How to get the sheet's tab color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

My `xls` file contains sheet with different tab color as in the attached image

[image]

I would like to print the sheet name along with its tab color.

```
  import xlrd

  file_name = "/Users/prince/Downloads/xlsx1.xls"
  book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_name, on_demand=True)
  for sheet in book.sheets():
    print (sheet.name)
    print (sheet.tabColor)
```

Is there any API like  **sheet.tabColor** ?